# is this equivalent ? (int) listofobj?.Count() to (listofobj == null)?0:listofobj.Count();

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, null-coalescing

i have

```
List<someobjects> listOfObj;
```

i have some property where i'd like to return number of objects
i tried it like

```
get => (int)listOfObj?.Count();
```

but app crashes with System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException somewhere in xamarin.forms page initializecomponent (the above said property is binded to some control )

when i change code to

```
get => (listOfObj==null)?0: listOfObj.Count();
```

all works as expected .

i think these two versions are the same , but may be i'm missing something ?

tia 
ish

Comment: *i think these two versions are the same* you are wrong ... in first you obviously trying cast `null` to `int` **edit:** long story `listOfObj?.Count()` in fact return `Nullable<int>` which is not null but when it doesn't has value it cannot be casted to int

Comment: What happened when you tried them?

Comment: If you want an alternative, you can use `get => listOfObj?.Count() ?? 0;`

Comment: No, it's not the equivalent. The equivavelent would be: `listOfObj?.Count() ?? 0` === `(listOfObj==null) ? 0 : listOfObj.Count()`

Comment: thanks, i hit post too early ;) for some reasons i thought that this cast (int) (int?) will do value == null ?? default (int). but i was wrong